# How to fix the Alamofire 5 error for success and failure cases in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

In my project, I am using Alamofire 5.9.3 and below is the uploading the data into the server.

```
    APISessionController.sharedInstance.sessionManager().upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }, to:url)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
                
            case .success(let upload, _, _): // Getting Error: '_' can only appear in a pattern or on the left side of an assignment
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                        self.delegate.uploadProgress(Progress.fractionCompleted)
                })
                
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if let JSON = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
}

            case .failure(_): //Getting Error : '_' can only appear in a pattern or on the left side of an assignment
```

Previoulsy I was using Alamofire 4.9.1, It was working fine. But it’s showing error in Alamofire 5?

Comment: check your request method is correct or not

Comment: What's `result` (now)? What if you let autocompletion for the `case`?

Comment: What's `APISessionController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alamofire's multipart upload APIs changed in Alamofire 5. The encoding completion closure is no longer necessary, you can just use the normal Alamofire APIs.

```swift
APISessionController.sharedInstance.sessionManager().upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }, to:url)
  .uploadProgress { }
  .response { }
```